# ReferenceError: sass is not defined

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

When I configured gulp and running task for scss, I am getting Error saying   *ReferenceError: sass is not defined* even I have installed gulp-scss and declared in gulp.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var scss = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/mystyles.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try `npm install gulp-sass@beta`

Comment: Installation doesn't had problem, I was requiring gulp-sass as scss as @AKX said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are `require`ing `gulp-sass` as `scss`, so either

- change that to `var sass = ...`, or
- the invocation to `scss()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the [link](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass/releases/tag/v3.0.0)

You now have to choose whether you want `node-sass` or `dart-sass` by installing one of them yourself and setting it in the options.

Don't forget `const sass = require('node-sass')` or `const sass = require('dart-sass')`.

Add it to your project as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var scss = require('gulp-sass');
var sass = require('sass');  // This you need to add

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/mystyles.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

Also please make sure you have npm install sass using npm i sass --save-dev